# How to resolve "Retrieving COM Class factory for component with CLSID" error with the Abbyy Addon in G1ANT studio?

Tags: rpa, abbyy, g1ant

[Getting an Error message: "Retrieving COM class for component CLSID"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMFnu.png) when trying to use the Abbyy Addon in G1ANT Studio.

Here is the code:

```
addon ocrabbyy version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

chrome g1ant.com
window ✱G1ANT✱ style maximize
ocrabbyy.fromscreen 170⫽250⫽1500⫽800
dialog ♥result
```

As suggested in another reply to a question with a similar issue, I tried enabling IIS in the control panel, yet It does not resolve the issue.

Comment: In order to use G1ANT.Addon.OcrAbbyy, you need to have a valid paid licence for ocr abbyy. Please check if you own it.