# Why robot gives me error whenever i use "addon ocrabbyy" commands?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I have tried to use different commands of "addon ocrabbyy" in different robots but it always gives me the same error and I even don't know its meaning. Can someone explain what's going wrong?[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message? If you do that, you will find plenty of solutions to the problem, which amounts to you trying to use a component on your system that is not installed.  Identify the component, install it correctly and try this again

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my question here which addresses this issue: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57950505/11998441)

You need to own a license for the software to be able to use the addon.